# extend twitter bootstrap carousel so that transitions are diagonal

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions, transition

I am trying to modify the twitter [bootstrap carousel](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel) so that rather than sliding in straight from the side the items slide in diagonally.

Its done with css3 transitions so presumably by adding ones for top or bottom in addition to the left and right ones that bootstrap has already defined then this should be achievable. I can't seem to get it to work though. This is what I have so far:

```css
.item.next.left {
  top: 50px;
}
.item.left {
  top: 0px;
  -moz-transition: top 0.6s ease-in-out 0s, left 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.item.active {
  top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1500X500" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1500X500" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

This sort of does what I want as the transition comes in from the top right but its not ideal since the slide finishes 50px down from where it should be. Ideally it should start higher and finish in the right place. I need it to come in from the bottom right towards the top left when I hit next. Anyone know how this can be achieved?

UPDATE:

OK I've had a bit of luck in that I can get it to come in from the bottom right for next transtion with this code:

```
.carousel-inner > .item { top:47px; }
.carousel-inner > .item.active { top:0; }
.carousel-inner > .next.left { top:0px; -moz-transition:top 0.6s ease-in-out 0s, left 0.6s ease-in-out 0s; }
```

And I can make it come in from the top left for the previous transition with this code:

```
.carousel-inner > .item { top:-47px; }
.carousel-inner > .item.active.right { top:0; }
.carousel-inner > .prev.right { top:0px; -moz-transition:top 0.6s ease-in-out 0s, left 0.6s ease-in-out 0s; }
```

So I need to somehow combine the two if it's possible. However since they both rely on a different top value being set for .carousel-inner > .item I don't know if there is a way round this